'apply_filters' is breaking some shortcodes/HTML but not all
I am using AJAX to periodically reload the content in an article in order to create a 'live' page.
This works fine for plain text and some basic HTML. But other HTML and shortcodes I add to the articles are lost when the new content is loaded in.
For example, while the following works correctly:
If I type a sentence and include <a href="https://www.google.com">a simple link</a> it works.

If I add an 'img' tag such as this no image appears in the article:
<img src="[DOMAIN]/picture.jpg" />

Much the same happens if I use an image shortcode - the [caption... portion is converted into <figure id=... but the 'img' tag is lost.
Similarly, if I try to embed a post from X, such as:
https://x.com/guilhernunes_/status/1820271713327665577

The image in it does not appear.
I am using apply_filters to process the content. The code is below. Can anyone see why some of the HTML is being altered when the page refreshes?
functions.php
function reload_article_content() {
    check_ajax_referer('reload_article_nonce', 'security');

    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);

    // only run on posts where 'is-live' custom field is set to 'true'
    if (get_post_meta($post_id, 'is-live', true) === 'true') {
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        if ($post) {
            // prepare the article content
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
            wp_send_json_success(array('content' => $content));
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('Post not found');
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Post is not live');
    }

    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_reload_article', 'reload_article_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_reload_article', 'reload_article_content');

function enqueue_reload_script() {
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'is-live', true) === 'true') {
        wp_enqueue_script('livepage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/livepage.js', array(), null, true);

        wp_localize_script('livepage', 'livepage_ajax_object', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('reload_article_nonce'),
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
        ));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_reload_script');

livepage.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function stripHTML(html) {
        var tmp = document.createElement('DIV');
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || '';
    }

    function reloadArticle() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', livepage_ajax_object.ajax_url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var oldContent = document.getElementById('article-content-old');
                var newContent = document.getElementById('article-content-new');

                if (!oldContent || !newContent) {
                    console.error('Required content elements not found.');
                    return;
                }

                // strip content for comparison
                var oldContentStripped = stripHTML(oldContent.innerHTML).trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                var newContentStripped = stripHTML(response.data.content).trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

                // compare stripped content
                if (newContentStripped !== oldContentStripped) {
                    // Fade out the old content
                    oldContent.style.opacity = 0;

                    // update the content with the full HTML
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log(response.data.content);
                        oldContent.innerHTML = response.data.content;
                        oldContent.style.opacity = 1;
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    console.log('No new content');
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
            }
        };

        var params = 'action=reload_article&security=' + livepage_ajax_object.ajax_nonce + '&post_id=' + livepage_ajax_object.post_id;
        xhr.send(params);
    }

    setInterval(reloadArticle, 60000);

    reloadArticle();
});

Before (as entered into editor)
Here is a regular chunk of text with some <strong>bold</strong>, some <em>italic</em> and a <a href="https://www.bing.com/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">link</a>.

Here's an image:

<img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/e7ea/live/3143d840-5b17-11ef-9256-fbeae1bb95b3.png.webp" alt="Flavio Briatore" width="470" height="314" class="size-medium wp-image-540235" />

Here's an image placed using the WordPress shortcode:

[caption id="attachment_540193" align="alignnone" width="470"]<img src="https://www.fs.usda.gov/sites/default/files/styles/original/public/2024-08/appalachian-trail-thunder-hill.jpg" alt="A tree" width="470" height="313" class="size-medium wp-image-540193" /> A tree[/caption]
  
And here's some more text.

After 1 (initial render in browser)
<div id="article-content-container" class="content-container">
<div id="article-content-old" class="article-content">
<p>1</p>
<p>Here is a regular chunk of text with some <strong>bold</strong>, some <em>italic</em> and a <a href="https://www.bing.com/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
<p>Here’s an image:</p>
<p><img fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/e7ea/live/3143d840-5b17-11ef-9256-fbeae1bb95b3.png.webp" alt="Flavio Briatore" width="470" height="314" class="size-medium wp-image-540235"></p>
<p>Here’s an image placed using the WordPress shortcode:</p>
<figure id="attachment_540193" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-540193" style="width: 470px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><img decoding="async" src="https://www.fs.usda.gov/sites/default/files/styles/original/public/2024-08/appalachian-trail-thunder-hill.jpg" alt="A tree" width="470" height="313" class="size-medium wp-image-540193"><figcaption id="caption-attachment-540193" class="wp-caption-text">A tree</figcaption></figure>
<p>And here’s some more text.</p>
</div>
<div id="article-content-new" class="article-content new-content"></div>
</div>

After 2 (once reloaded via AJAX)
In browser:
<div id="article-content-container" class="content-container">
<div id="article-content-old" class="article-content" style="opacity: 1;"><p>Here is a regular chunk of text with some <strong>bold</strong>, some <em>italic</em> and a <a href="https://www.bing.com/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
<p>Here’s an image:</p>
<p></p>
<p>Here’s an image placed using the WordPress shortcode:</p>
<figure id="attachment_540193" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-540193" style="width: 470px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><figcaption id="caption-attachment-540193" class="wp-caption-text">A tree</figcaption></figure>
<p>And here’s some more text.</p>
</div>
<div id="article-content-new" class="article-content new-content"></div>
</div>

From response.data.content:
<p>Here is a regular chunk of text with some <strong>bold</strong>, some <em>italic</em> and a <a href="https://www.bing.com/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
<p>Here&#8217;s an image:</p>
<p></p>
<p>Here&#8217;s an image placed using the WordPress shortcode:</p>
<figure id="attachment_540193" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-540193" style="width: 470px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><figcaption id="caption-attachment-540193" class="wp-caption-text">A tree</figcaption></figure>
<p>And here&#8217;s some more text.</p>

From REST API ('rendered'):
"<p>Here is a regular chunk of text with some <strong>bold</strong>, some <em>italic</em> and a <a href=\"https://www.bing.com/\" rel=\"noopener\" target=\"_blank\">link</a>.</p>\n<p>Here&#8217;s an image:</p>\n<p></p>\n<p>Here&#8217;s an image placed using the WordPress shortcode:</p>\n<figure id=\"attachment_540193\" aria-describedby=\"caption-attachment-540193\" style=\"width: 470px\" class=\"wp-caption alignnone\"><figcaption id=\"caption-attachment-540193\" class=\"wp-caption-text\">A tree</figcaption></figure>\n<p>And here&#8217;s some more text.</p>\n"


it sounds like you're retrieving raw post content, though I'm not sure why there's an old custom admin AJAX handler when you could make a request to the REST API endpoint that already exists in WordPress and extract the fully rendered data there? example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/12345 where 12345 is the post ID should return a JSON object that contains the post title/ID/content/etc. I'd be suspicious of the stripping operation in the code, likewise script execution inside the new HTML. Can you provide direct before/after examples rather than using descriptions?

Thanks for the quick reply. I know very little of REST API and as I've spent so long on this already I'd prefer to try to make this  solution work than try a whole new approach.
After looking into this further it seems adding links to X/Twitter was causing the code to incorrectly trigger on occasions when no changes had been made to the content. I can live without Twitter embeds, so forget about those, but I really need to get images working.
I've added a full 'before' and 'after' example to the original post, hope that helps.

the HTML after via AJAX, is what you're seeing in the browser the same as what the AJAX response contains? Check in the network panel by looking at the request

The two are the same. I've added what I get via 'response.data.content' to 'After 2' in the question.

while I suspect the filters on the_content may not be the same, does the REST API response look like the AJAX response in the content field or does it differ?

I'm sorry, I've no experience at all of using REST API and I don't know how to use it to generate a response like this. Is it something you can easily tell me how to do?

@notpoppy go to the url wp-json/wp... quoted in the first comment and you will see the result.

You don't need experience, it's a URL that responds with JSON, its purpose is the same as the admin-ajax.php system you're already using but with pretty URLs, and you interact with it in the same way. You can check what I asked by visiting the REST API URL in the browser and looking at the result /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/IDGOESHERE

e.g. here's my current latest blogpost via REST API: https://tomjn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1129, if I wanted to fetch it in javascript I'd do it the same way as anything else e.g. fetch(... or jQuery.get( .... etc

Thanks very much - I'll take a look at that and give it a try (probably not until the start of next week now).

Okay thanks for all your help with that - I've added the 'rendered' portion of the REST API call to the original post.

try this:
function reload_article_content() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'reload_article_nonce', 'security' );

    $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );

    // only run on posts where 'is-live' custom field is set to 'true'
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'is-live', true ) === 'true' ) {
        $post = get_post( $post_id );

        if ( $post ) {
            $GLOBALS['post'] = $post;
            setup_postdata( $post );

            ob_start();
            the_content();
            $content = ob_get_contents();

            wp_send_json_success( [ 'content' => $content ] );
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error( 'Post not found' );
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Post is not live' );
    }

    wp_die();
}


Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it hasn't worked. Trying to see why at the moment.
